# Concluding the solutions of two complex integrals from one.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to solve the following question:

Compute the following integrals:

$$ 
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{|dz|}{|z - \frac{i}{2}|^2}\;,\quad
 \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{dz}{(z - \frac{i}{2})^2}\;,\quad
 \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{dz}{(z - \frac{i}{2})}
$$

I am wondering, how can finding the solution of one of them leads to finding the solutions of the others? Or each integration should be solved separately? But I think there are some relations among these three integrals.

What is the importance of the absolute value in $|dz|$ in the first integral?

Any details about how to tackle this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $dz$ is complex number but $|dz|$ is real. For example, if you parametrize $z=e^{it}$, then $dz = i e^{it}dt$ but $|dz| = dt$

Comment: @NinadMunshi so useful information thank you!

Comment: You need to compute all three. Similar-looking integrals sometimes require vastly different techniques (or some are elementary and others aren't, e.g., $\int xe^{x^{2}}\,dx$ versus $\int x^{2} e^{x^{2}}\, dx$).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang but it was a question in a 2 hour exam out of 5 problems that  must be solved, so I am assuming that it should be solved in not more than 20 minutes that is why I am asking here.

Comment: 1. Depending on the tools available, two of the integrals can be evaluated by inspection. 2. I trust this exam was over before the question was asked. Either way, best wishes with your studies.

Comment: Yes, it is an exam from 2016 @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Could you please explain to me how 2 integrals can be evaluated by inspection and which tools will we depend on? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: I think the second and third ones can be done fairly easily. Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: For (a),, it is actually a real integral. You can solve it using some trigonometric substitution. Alternatively, you can convert back to a complex integral using the fact that along the unit circle, $\sin t = \frac{z - z^{-1}}{2i}$, $dt = \frac{dz}{iz}$, and then use residue theorem.

Comment: I know the theorem but actually I do not know how to use it unfortunately, can you provide some details please? @Bio

Answer (score 2):

- (a) Applying substitution
  $$\;z=e^{it},\quad t\in(0,2\pi),\quad|\text dz|=|ie^{it}\,\text dt|=2\,\text dt,\tag1$$
  (pointed in the OP comments), one can get
  $$I_a=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\text dt}{\left(\frac12-\sin2t \right)^2+\cos^22t}
  =4\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\text dt}{5-4\sin t}
  =4\int\limits_0^\pi\dfrac{10\,\text dt}{25-16\sin^2 t}$$
  $$=\dfrac{80}9\int\limits_0^{\large\frac\pi2}\dfrac{\text dt}{\left(\tan^2t+\dfrac{25}9\right)\cos^2t}\,
  =\dfrac{16}{3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{3\tan t}5\right)\bigg|_0^{\large\frac\pi2},$$
  $$I_a=\dfrac83\,\pi.\tag2$$
- (b) Applying substitution
  $$z=\dfrac12w,\quad \text dz=\dfrac12\,\text dw.\tag3, $$
  one can get
  $$I_b(n)=\int\limits_{|z|=1} \dfrac{\text dz}{\left(z-\frac i2\right)^n}
  =2^{n-1}\int\limits_{|w|=2} \dfrac{\text dw}{\left(w-i\right)^n},$$
  wherein
  $$f_n(w)=\dfrac1{\left(w-i\right)^{n}}=c_{n,0}+\dfrac{c_{n,-1}}{w-i}+\dfrac{c_{n,-2}}{(w-i)^2}+\dots.$$
  Then
  $$I_b(n)=2^{n-1}\cdot2\pi i c_{n,-1},$$
  $$I_b(1)=2\pi i,\quad I_b(2)=0.\tag4$$

Comment: I believe the singular point in the denominator is $i/2$, not $1/2$. Also, in (a), OP has a square as in $|z-i/2|^2$ not $|z-i/2|$.

Comment: @ripples Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For any smooth curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ and a holomorphic function $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ where $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is an open connected set that contains the image of the curve, the integral $\int_\gamma f(z)|dz|$ is defined as:
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)|dz|:=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt
$$

So your first integral is
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|e^{it}-\frac{i}{2}|^2}|ie^{it}|dt
=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|e^{it}-\frac{i}{2}|^2}dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos^2t+(\sin t+\frac12)^2}dt
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac1{\frac54+\sin t}\;dt
=\frac{8\pi}{3}
\end{align}
$$
where you can calculate by the substitution $u=\tan(t/2)$.

The second and the third ones are trivial by the residue theorem because they are already in the form of the Laurent series (only one term!) and you can read the coefficient of $\dfrac{1}{z-i/2}$ in the expansion directly. So
$$
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z-i/2)^2}=2\pi i\cdot 0=0\quad
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z-i/2}=2\pi i\cdot 1=2\pi i
$$